# Adjusting constraints programmatically do they need to be first removed and then re-added?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have a function in my code to adjust the layout of some buttons. This is called when .hidden is set.

```
   private func layoutButtons() {

        redButton.hidden = !redButtonEnabled
        redButtonLabel.hidden = !redButtonEnabled
        yellowButton.hidden = !yellowButtonEnabled
        yellowButtonLabel.hidden = !yellowButtonEnabled

        removeConstraint(yellowButtonTrailingContraint)
        if yellowButtonEnabled && !redButtonEnabled {
            yellowButtonTrailingContraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: yellowButton, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -horizontalMargin)
        } else {
            yellowButtonTrailingContraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: yellowButton, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: redButton, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -horizontalMargin)
        }
        addConstraint(yellowButtonTrailingContraint)
    }
```

Is is necessary to first remove the constraint before changing it and then re-add it afterwards as I have done above? Saw this in an example somewhere but seems a bit odd. An pointers on this would be really appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, removing a constraint is an option, but its not always necessary.

You can sometimes edit a constraint by changing its constant value, which will update the layout.
For example :

```
    var constraintHeight = NSLayoutConstraint(item: someView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy:.Equal, toItem:nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 100)
    someView.addConstraint(constraintHeight)
    ...
    //The Constraint can be edited later by changing the constant value
    constraintHeight.constant = 200
    someView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

OR you can activate or deactivate them, For example :

```
    var constraintHeight1 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: someView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy:.Equal, toItem:nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 100)
    var constraintHeight2 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: someView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy:.Equal, toItem:nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 200)
    constraintHeight1.active = true
    constraintHeight2.active = false

    someView.addConstraint(constraintHeight1)
    someView.addConstraint(constraintHeight2)

    ...
    //Later you can set the other constraint as active
    constraintHeight1.active = false
    constraintHeight2.active = true
    someView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

At any given point only the active constraints will be used to decide the final layout of the view. So, you have few alternatives, but we have to make sure that never two conflicting constraints are active, or else the app will crash. We will have to remove one of the conflicting constraints or deactivate it. Hope it helps :]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Helped me a lot. My example above it doesn't need to be removed and added again? Surely just calling layoutIfNeeded will suffice.

Comment: @Kex constraint removal in runtime is almost always causes a performance hit, so it doesn't recommended. Deactivation or simply changing a constant value (or multiplier) should be on the first place.